# Root launching vncserver as different user

Tags: vnc

I have a system I'm administering that is shared by many users, each having a separate VNC session. So far they've been launching their own VNC servers from SSH, but I'd rather be the only one able to spin up new servers.

In other words, I want the root user to be the only one with permission to run `vncserver`. The problem I'm facing is how to run a vnc session for a user while keeping the `vncserver` program unavailable for the users to run it.

I've checked the docs of both `vncserver` and `Xvnc` and I haven't found any option resembling `--user` or something similar.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score -1):

1) In order to avoid certain users to your (*1) vncserver, the easiest way would be to change perms for vncserver binary to avoid others to run it and create a vncgrp group.

```
$ sudo groupadd vncgrp
$ sudo chown root:vncgrp /usr/bin/tightvncserver
$ sudo chmod 750 /usr/bin/tightvncserver
```

(*1) Mind you, they might download and run their vncserver, and this becomes a harder problem.
You might run into issues when upgrading the vnc package, or, depending the package manager configuration, it might restore original perms and anyone might be able to run vnc.

2) Running vncserver under some other user credentials can be achieved using sudo.

```
$ sudo -u someonelse /usr/bin/tightvncserver
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood my question completely. I don't have a separate group of users that shouldn't use vncserver. No user other than root should be able to run `vncserver`. The problem is that, in order to create a vnc session for a user, the command needs to be run by that user. That's the issue.

Comment: Well, if you'd like to restrict *just* root to your your vncserver, just change the permissions accordinly. 
chmod 500 /usr/bin/tightvncserver
Also, you might want to restrict your users hability to run binaries from their home directory.
Create a new filesystem for /home and mount it as nodev,noexec, for examlple.